# Possible to Push src code to BitBucket repository using access token?

Tags: bitbucket

Is there anyway to Push source code to Bitbucket repo using access token.. If know kindly inform me guys.. Tnanks in advance guys..

I used below format to push the source code but it does not work for me.

```
git push https://x-token-auth:{access_token}@bitbucket.org
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can push to a repository using an OAuth 2 Bearer token. Note that this must be a valid OAuth 2 Bearer token. OAuth 1 Access tokens are not supported (as OAuth 1 requires each request to be signed individually).

The incomplete fragment you pasted looks ok, but the lack of output doesn't allow for more insightful feedback on what might be going wrong.

It might be best to contact us at support@bitbucket.org and share more details: the full shell output, the consumer key and where possible all HTTP headers (which you can get Git to dump to stdout using the `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` environment variable).

Before you contact us though, make sure you're using OAuth 2 (not 1) and that your bearer token is current (they expire after an hour and must then be refreshed) and that your token has the "repository" scope, which is required to access any repo data (check your OAuth Consumer page for this).

Here's the relevant documentation: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/concepts/oauth2.html

Comment: The page doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to push your src code to BitBucket using accessToken via commandLine. 
You can refer the developers BitBucket doc [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/concepts/oauth2.html)

Comment: The page doesn't exist anymore.